# CIFS/SMB with inconsistent read/write permissions

Tags: smb, cifs

I have a CIFS/SMB file server which I mount onto my local Linux machine (Ubuntu), with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<Server> /mnt/sharedDrive/ -o  username=<USERNAME>,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

Now, for the most part, everything works as expected, I can read and write files just fine. However, some programs do not run properly complaining they can not create file XYZ because of missing permissions.

I know this is really unspecific, but I have no idea how to even figure out why some commands (touch, mkdir etc.) work just fine, while others do not (e.g. the creation of a conda environment by snakemake), and whether I can fix it by mounting the file server in a different way or whether it is the configuration of the smb drive (which is out of my hand).

Again, sorry for being so unspecific, but does anyone have an idea on how I can get to the root of the problem?